# set ImageView depending on case

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

i have been looking for a while and could not find a solution for my problem. I am trying to set an imageView depending on the User logged in. The main problem is how do i rename `R.drawable.stock` into `R.drawable.user1`where the name of the imageView varies with the name of the user. I tried setting it to a string like `String temp="R.drawable."+userNameStore;` but did not have luck.

Here is what i am doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    SharedPreferences app_preferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userNameStore = 
        app_preferences.getString("userNameStore", null);

    String temp="R.drawable."+userNameStore;

    TextView textName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    textName.setText("Username: "+ userNameStore);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 2 methods in my utility class for this:

```
public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
}

public static int getRawResourceId(Context context, String rawName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + rawName, null, context.getPackageName());
}
```

So if you have an image resource in your drawable folder named `user1`, you could get and use its ID like this:

`imageView.setImageResource(getImageId(this, "user1"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use getIdentier, for example:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("star_off", "string", getPackageName());
```

Check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

In your case it should be something like:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(temp, "drawable", getPackageName());
...
image.setImageResource(resID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your string identifier like this...

int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());

It's covered [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)